# Get a random id from an array that does not exist in two other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to generate a random ID on a very explicit set of requirements.

There are 3 arrays `itemsAvailable`, `itemsSeen`, and `itemsTaken`.

`itemsAvailable` looks like this: `[{ id: 1, ... }, ...]` an array of objects with various fields, the other fields don't matter for the purposes of this functionality, we are only concerned with the `id` field. It is a number that is `1 -> X`, X increasing by 1 for each item present.

`itemsSeen` is just an array of the ids that a user has seen, so if they saw ids for `1, 7, 16` it would look like `itemsSeen = [1, 7, 16]`.

`itemsTaken` is also just an array of the ids they have seen that they chose to take, for example, `itemsTaken = [1, 16]`. They can only take items that have been present in `itemsSeen`.

At the start of the function, a random id is generated based on the length of `itemsAvailable`. Each item's id will match its index position.

If `itemsSeen` or `itemsTaken` includes the random id, generate a new one in the bounds of the length of `itemsAvailable` until it is not present in either array.

When a number is generated and shown to the user, it should be added to `itemsSeen` array. If that item is picked it should be added to `itemsAvailable` array. Then get a random item from `itemsAvaialbe` again.

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-cdn-kiouc?file=/src/index.js) of what I have.

Comment: please add the code to the question.

Comment: "Each item's id will match its index position." -- Array indexes start at 0, but your IDs start at 1. So presumably each item's ID will be its index + 1.

Comment: You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Put all the IDs into an `itemsUnseen` array. PIck a random element of this array. Remove the element from `itemsUnseen` and add it to `itemsSeen`.

Comment: Barmar, ids start at 0 for actual items, this was just a mockup of the general layout. Wil try that real fast and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar for helping simplify the solution.

I changed the implementation to only use two arrays, picking a random item from the first array, removing it, and then adding it to the second array.

```
var itemsAvailable = [];
var currentItem;

for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
  itemsAvailable.push({ id: i });
}

var itemsSeen = [{ id: 3 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 16 }];

const getRandomId = (arr, length) => {
  var r = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)];

  if (itemsSeen.includes(r)) {
    r = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)];
  }

  return r;
};

const generateRandomId = () => {
  if (itemsAvailable.length === 0) {
    return;
  }
  var nextItem = getRandomId(itemsAvailable, itemsAvailable.length);
  itemsSeen.push(nextItem);
  itemsAvailable = itemsAvailable.filter((item) => item !== nextItem);
  currentItem = nextItem;
};
```